# Accessing Stormpath Custom Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, passport.js, stormpath

I want to access the custom data of a user to save to a js variable of the client js file. I was trying something like this:

**Index.js (route file)**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     var param = req.user.customData
     res.send(param);
});
```

**Script.js(client file)**

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'/',
    data:'param',
    success:function(data){
        alert(data)
    },
    error:function(error){
        alert(error)
    }
})
```

However this returns a very strange output. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The output is the html code for the page associated with script.js

Comment: Do you have another route handler for '/'? Did you try defining another route like '/data' to check if that works?

Comment: I have a similar post request which also deals with '/' should I do something different for GET?

Comment: The post request works by the way which is why i mentioned it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've reformatted your code to make it easier to read so others can more easily help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) and I should be able to help.

It does sound like there is another route handler which is trying to serve the HTML page for your front end app, so this route handler you're showing may not be reached.

It would also be helpful to see how you've setup the Stormpath middleware.  Feel free to contact us on https://support.stormpath.com/, you can share your code with us and we can help debug!